# Como ajustar al grid de la pantalla de Visual Studio diferentes butones?

Tags: c#, wpf

Muy buenas, ya se que últimamente hago muchas preguntas pero cada vez que me adentro mas en Visual Studio, mas dudas y preguntas me surgen. Alguien podría decirme como podría hacer un autoajuste de diferentes buttons o controladores rectangle con la pantalla de WPF de Visual Studio? Es decir, tengo conectada la Kinect y la pantalla esta autoajustada, si la aumento se aumenta también la pantalla de Kinect de salida, entonces ahora me gustaría hacer lo mismo con los buttons (controladores) o si se puede incrustarlos en la pantalla. Alguien sabe si es posible? Muchas Gracias
dejo la parte del código que CREO QUE ES DONDE ESTA ESE AUTO AJUSTE aunque no estoy seguro:

```
          if (dataReceived)
        {
            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {

                // Draw a transparent background to set the render size 
              dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, this.displayWidth, this.displayHeight));





                int penIndex = 0;
                foreach (Body body in this.bodies)
                {
                    Pen drawPen = this.bodyColors[penIndex++];




                    if (body.IsTracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawClippedEdges(body, dc);

                        IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints = body.Joints;
                        // Console.WriteLine("HandRight" + JointType.HandRight);

                        // convert the joint points to depth (display) space
                        Dictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints = new Dictionary<JointType, Point>();
                        Joint handLeft = joints[JointType.HandLeft];
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando WPF, te sugiero utilizar `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="*">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="*">
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Cuando asignas `*` a `Width` en las columnas o `Height` en los renglones, le estás indicando que asigne el tamaño sobrante, en este ejemplo hay dos columnas con `Width="*"` lo que se traduce que el tamaño de la pantalla será dividido entre ambas columnas.

Para indicarle al botón en qué columna estará, se usa la propiedad `Grid.Column="[colum_index]"`, el botón al no tener un tamaño fijo, tomará el tamaño de la columna.

Para mayor información puede revisar la documentación de Microsoft [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Puedes ayudarte en los siguientes ejemplos: [Ejemplo 1](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid/) y [Ejemplo 2](https://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html).